# how to issue a "show dbs" from pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and I can't figure out how to execute the mongodb interactive shell equivalent of "show dbs".

Comment: Too extensive. Not easy to find what you need via the only terms that you know.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# Assuming youre running mongod on 'localhost' with port 27017
c = MongoClient('localhost',27017)
c.database_names()
```

Update 2020:

> DeprecationWarning: database_names is deprecated

Use the following:

```py
c.list_database_names()
```

Comment: Updating Answer as Connection()is now deprecated: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/connection.html

Comment: `database_names` is now deprecated, we should use `list_database_names` instead.

`for current_database in cliente.list_database_names():`

Answer (score 13):

as today it's

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# client = MongoClient('host', port_number)
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
cursor = client.list_databases()
for db in cursor:
    print(db)
```

or

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
# client = MongoClient('host', port_number)
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
for db in client.list_databases():
    print(db)
```

If you use database_names, you will get "DeprecationWarning: database_names is deprecated. Use list_database_names instead."

Answer (score 5):

With Python3.5, you can try this way

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
print(client.list_database_names())
```